# Can't seem to keep my DropZone state(s) updated/always rerenders React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my app is a form that has `dropZone`s (amongst other things) and an `Add Questions` button that adds another `dropZone` to the form. Whenever I put an image in my `dropZone` and then click `Add Question` the image disappears. [Here's a CodeSandbox of the whole app.](https://codesandbox.io/s/1vy36n4wy4)

But if you prefer relevant code only, here's my `DropZone` component followed by my `AddQuestionButton` component:

```
class DropZone extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.dropZoneRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      fileBlob: props.fileBlob,
      fileId: props.fileId
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this._onDragEnter = this._onDragEnter.bind(this);
    this._onDragLeave = this._onDragLeave.bind(this);
    this._onDragOver = this._onDragOver.bind(this);
    this._onDrop = this._onDrop.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(file = "") {
    this.setState({
      fileBlob: URL.createObjectURL(file)
    });
    console.log(this.state.fileBlob + "OMG")
    //document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.state.file + ')';
  }

  handleUpdate(){

  }

  componentDidMount(event) {
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragenter", this._onDragEnter);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragleave", this._onDragLeave);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
    window.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
      e = e || event;
      e.preventDefault();
    },false);
    window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
      e = e || event;
      e.preventDefault();
    },false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("dragenter", this._onDragEnter);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("dragleave", this._onDragLeave);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
  }

  _onDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }

      _onDragLeave(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }

      _onDrop(e, event) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.handleChange(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
        let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        console.log("Files dropped: ", files);
        // Upload files
        console.log(this.state.fileBlob);
        return false;
      }

      render() {
        const labelId = uuid();
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              type="file"
              id={labelId}
              name={this.state.fileBlobId}
              className="inputFile"

              onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.files[0])}
            />
            <label htmlFor={labelId} value={this.state.fileBlob}>
              {this.props.children}
              <div className="dropZone" id="dragbox" key={this.state.fileBlobId} ref={this.dropZoneRef} onChange={this.handleChange} onDrop={this._onDrop}>
                Drop or Choose File {console.log(this.dropZoneRef)}
                <img src={this.state.fileBlob} id="pic" name="file" accept="image/*" />
              </div>
            </label>
            <div />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    class AddQuestionButton extends Component {
  addQuestion = () => {
    this.props.onClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="addQuestionButtonDiv">
        <button id="button" onClick={this.addQuestion} />
        <label id="addQuestionButton" onClick={this.addQuestion}>
          Add Question
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the direct parent of the `DropZone` component, `Question`:

```
class Question extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: props.value.question,
      uniqueId: props.value.uniqueId,
      answers: props.value.answers,
      file: props.file
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({
      question: value
    });
    this.props.onUpdate({
      uniqueId: this.state.uniqueId,
      value
    });
  }

  handleUpdate(event, file) {
    //if ("1" == 1) // true
    //if ("1" === 1) //false
    var questions = this.state.questions.slice();

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (questions[i].uniqueId == event.uniqueId) {
        questions[i].file = event.value;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState(() => ({
      questions: questions
    }));

    console.log(event, questions);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id={"questionDiv" + questionIdx} key={myUUID + questionIdx + 1}>
        Question<br />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.question}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          key={this.state.uniqueId}
          name="question"
        />
        <DropZone file={this.state.file}/>
        <Answers
          updateAnswers={this.props.updateAnswers}
          answers={this.state.answers}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And `Question`'s parent component, `Questions':

```
class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: []
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    this.removeQuestion = this.removeQuestion.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate(event) {
    //if ("1" == 1) // true
    //if ("1" === 1) //false
    var questions = this.state.questions.slice();

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (questions[i].uniqueId == event.uniqueId) {
        questions[i].question = event.value;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState(() => ({
      questions: questions
    }));

    console.log(event, questions);
  }

  updateAnswers(answers, uniqueId) {
    const questions = this.state.questions;
    questions.forEach(question => {
      if (question.uniqueId === uniqueId) {
        question.answers = answers;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      questions
    });
  }

  addQuestion = question => {
    questionIdx++;
    var newQuestion = {
      uniqueId: uuid(),
      question: "",
      file: { fileBlob: "", fileId: uuid()},
      answers: [
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false },
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false },
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false },
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false }
      ]
    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      questions: [...prevState.questions, newQuestion]
    }));
    return { questions: newQuestion };
  };

  removeQuestion(uniqueId, questions) {
    this.setState(({ questions }) => {
      var questionRemoved = this.state.questions.filter(
        props => props.uniqueId !== uniqueId
      );
      return { questions: questionRemoved };
    });
    console.log(
      "remove button",
      uniqueId,
      JSON.stringify(this.state.questions, null, " ")
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="questions">
        <ol id="quesitonsList">
          {this.state.questions.map((value, index) => (
            <li key={value.uniqueId}>
              {
                <RemoveQuestionButton
                  onClick={this.removeQuestion}
                  value={value.uniqueId}
                />
              }
              {
                <Question
                  onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
                  value={value}
                  number={index}
                  updateAnswers={answers =>
                    this.updateAnswers(answers, value.uniqueId)
                  }
                />
              }
              {<br />}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ol>
        <AddQuestionButton onClick={this.addQuestion} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only keep state in the top level component, and you should be good to go.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

var uuid = require("uuid-v4");
// Generate a new UUID
var myUUID = uuid();
// Validate a UUID as proper V4 format
uuid.isUUID(myUUID); // true

class DropZone extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.dropZoneRef = React.createRef();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this._onDragEnter = this._onDragEnter.bind(this);
    this._onDragLeave = this._onDragLeave.bind(this);
    this._onDragOver = this._onDragOver.bind(this);
    this._onDrop = this._onDrop.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(file = "") {
    this.props.updateFile(URL.createObjectURL(file), this.props.file.fileId);
    //document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.state.file + ')';
  }

  componentDidMount(event) {
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragenter", this._onDragEnter);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragleave", this._onDragLeave);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
    window.addEventListener(
      "dragover",
      function(e) {
        e = e || event;
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      false
    );
    window.addEventListener(
      "drop",
      function(e) {
        e = e || event;
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      false
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener(
      "dragenter",
      this._onDragEnter
    );
    this.dropZoneRef.current.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener(
      "dragleave",
      this._onDragLeave
    );
    this.dropZoneRef.current.removeEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
  }

  _onDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragLeave(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDrop(e, event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleChange(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log("Files dropped: ", files);
    // Upload files
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const labelId = uuid();
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          id={labelId}
          name={this.props.file.fileId}
          className="inputFile"
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <label htmlFor={labelId} value={this.props.file.fileBlob}>
          {this.props.children}
          <div
            className="dropZone"
            id="dragbox"
            key={this.props.file.fileId}
            ref={this.dropZoneRef}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onDrop={this._onDrop}
          >
            Drop or Choose File {console.log(this.dropZoneRef)}
            <img
              src={this.props.file.fileBlob}
              id="pic"
              name="file"
              accept="image/*"
            />
          </div>
        </label>
        <div />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Answers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answers: props.answers
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  // let event = {
  //   index: 1,
  //   value: 'hello'
  // };
  handleUpdate(event) {
    var answers = this.state.answers.slice();

    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      if (answers[i].answerId == event.answerId) {
        answers[i].answer = event.value;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState(() => ({
      answers: answers
    }));
    this.props.updateAnswers(answers);

    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="answers">
        Answer Choices<br />
        {this.state.answers.map((value, index) => (
          <Answer
            key={`${value}-${index}`}
            onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
            value={value}
            number={index}
            name="answer"
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Answer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answer: props.value.answer,
      answerId: props.value.answerId,
      isCorrect: props.value.isCorrect
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({
      answer: value
    });
    this.props.onUpdate({
      answerId: this.state.answerId,
      value
    });

    // let sample = {
    //   kyle: "toast",
    //   cam: "pine"
    // };

    // sample.kyle
    // sample.cam
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.answer}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          key={this.state.answerId}
          name="answer"
        />
        {/*console.log(this.state.answerId)*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var questionIdx = 0;

class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: []
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    this.removeQuestion = this.removeQuestion.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate(event) {
    //if ("1" == 1) // true
    //if ("1" === 1) //false
    var questions = this.state.questions.slice();

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (questions[i].uniqueId == event.uniqueId) {
        questions[i].question = event.value;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState(() => ({
      questions: questions
    }));

    console.log(event, questions);
  }

  updateAnswers(answers, uniqueId) {
    const questions = this.state.questions;
    questions.forEach(question => {
      if (question.uniqueId === uniqueId) {
        question.answers = answers;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      questions
    });
  }

  updateFile(fileBlob, fileId) {
    const questions = this.state.questions;
    questions.forEach(question => {
      if (question.file.fileId === fileId) {
        question.file.fileBlob = fileBlob;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      questions
    });
  }

  addQuestion = question => {
    questionIdx++;
    var newQuestion = {
      uniqueId: uuid(),
      question: "",
      file: { fileBlob: {}, fileId: uuid() },
      answers: [
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false },
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false },
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false },
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false }
      ]
    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      questions: [...prevState.questions, newQuestion]
    }));
    return { questions: newQuestion };
  };

  removeQuestion(uniqueId, questions) {
    this.setState(({ questions }) => {
      var questionRemoved = this.state.questions.filter(
        props => props.uniqueId !== uniqueId
      );
      return { questions: questionRemoved };
    });
    console.log(
      "remove button",
      uniqueId,
      JSON.stringify(this.state.questions, null, " ")
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="questions">
        <ol id="quesitonsList">
          {this.state.questions.map((value, index) => (
            <li key={value.uniqueId}>
              {
                <RemoveQuestionButton
                  onClick={this.removeQuestion}
                  value={value.uniqueId}
                />
              }
              {
                <Question
                  onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
                  value={value}
                  number={index}
                  updateAnswers={answers =>
                    this.updateAnswers(answers, value.uniqueId)
                  }
                  updateFile={this.updateFile.bind(this)}
                />
              }
              {<br />}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ol>
        <AddQuestionButton onClick={this.addQuestion} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Question extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.props.onUpdate({
      uniqueId: this.props.value.uniqueId,
      value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id={"questionDiv" + questionIdx} key={myUUID + questionIdx + 1}>
        Question<br />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.value.question}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          key={this.props.value.uniqueId}
          name="question"
        />
        <DropZone
          file={this.props.value.file}
          updateFile={this.props.updateFile}
        />
        <Answers
          updateAnswers={this.props.updateAnswers}
          answers={this.props.value.answers}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class IntroFields extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      author: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log([name]);
    this.setState((previousState, props) => ({
      [name]: value
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="IntroFields">
        Title:{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="title"
        />
        Author:{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.author}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="author"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AddQuestionButton extends Component {
  addQuestion = () => {
    this.props.onClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="addQuestionButtonDiv">
        <button id="button" onClick={this.addQuestion} />
        <label id="addQuestionButton" onClick={this.addQuestion}>
          Add Question
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RemoveQuestionButton extends Component {
  removeQuestion = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="removeQuestionButtonDiv">
        <button id="button" onClick={this.removeQuestion} key={uuid()} />
        <label
          id="removeQuestionButton"
          onClick={this.removeQuestion}
          key={uuid()}
        >
          Remove Question
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class BuilderForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="formDiv">
        <IntroFields />
        <Questions />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default BuilderForm;
```

You shouldn't be passing props into state like here from the `Question` component:

```
this.state = {
  question: props.value.question,
  uniqueId: props.value.uniqueId,
  answers: props.value.answers,
  file: props.file
};
```

Because then you're allowing two different components to have two logical sources of state that they believe to be the same. Keep one source of truth that has everything that its children depend on. If all of the children components don't depend on the data (state), consider moving it down a level to the state of the child, otherwise pass as props.

Comment: Thanks! It makes a little more sense now

Comment: Would you recommend I do the same for my `Answer` component?

Comment: Totally! You're getting the hang of it.

Comment: So I was able to do the same thing for the `Answer` component and now my checkbox states update correctly but when I click the `Add Question` button the visual of the checkbox does not match it's actually value. And I know for sure that the value is updating correctly. Do you have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Put an onChange listener and `value={this.props.value.isChecked}` (or something close to that) -- probably can reuse to some degree what you have for the input text items (handleChange method) -- on the html `<input type="checkbox" />`. Just like you're able to update 'answer' text in by calling `this.props.onUpdate()` in the `Answer` component, you should be able to modify the top-level state for the check input.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that I was using a `value` attribute instead of a `checked` attribute. Once I changed it it was all good :)